# How to monitor Nginx on Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I have installed Zabbix 4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have added one ubuntu 16.04 server as a Zabbix client. I am able to monitor client-server properly but now I want to monitor Nginx service on Zabbix UI.
I am trying to create the Item using `service.info[service,<param>]` key, but after creating the item it's showing  Not supported.

Please provide some adequate solution that will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to import the below Zabbix template and add hosts to this..

[Zabbix recommended Template](https://github.com/v-zhuravlev/zbx_template_nginx)